# pip 7.1.2 uninstall bug?

Tags: python, pip

I am seeing a strange error in pip 7.1.2. Anytime I do an uninstall I am seeing the error

`OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/vivekv/.environments/fpysvc/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fantain_muservice-0.1-py2.7.egg'`

It seems to be that 7.1.2 of pip seems to be strangely broken where it is looking for files in /local/lib/python2.7/... while the file actually exists in /lib/python2.7/..

The moment I  downgrade pip by doing a `pip install --upgrade pip=7.0.2` I see the problem go away magically.  Has anybody seen this issue with pip?

Comment: install a module without `required module` or `pip`  haven't any idea about of your default `python library path` !

Comment: This is a venv with default path removed out.  So that is not the issue.   I am seeing this for any package for example even django

Comment: Yeah ! `pip=7.1.2` for python27, python35 ? Different pip, different install dir, different python version. You got a lot possibility.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are saying.  I am using pip 7.1.2 on Python 2.7.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: please check `scripttest` and `virtualenv` version. Your error contained abnomal path!